# get Menu outside onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: android

Im looking to set an actionbar menu item visible from a helper class. Is it possible to access the actionbar Menu outside of onOptionsItemSelected through a reference to an activity? code below.

```
public boolean getMenuFromActivity(BaseActivity activity){
   // something like Menu menu =  activity.getActionBar().getMenu()?
   // then get menu item by id and set visibility..
   //return true if found
   return false
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple answer: Call `findItem()` on the `Menu` after you have inflated your menu resource in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, and hold onto that `MenuItem` in a data member of your activity, so you can use it later.

Slightly less-simple answer: Hold onto the `Menu` from `onCreateOptionsMenu()` in a data member of your activity, and use it later to find your item.